# Как в компоненте подключить свою таблицу вместо инфоблока?

Tags: битрикс

Как в компоненте подключить свою таблицу вместо инфоблока?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такого стандартного компонента нет, можно создать свой и в нем реализовать работу со своим классом.

Вот ссылка на офф док. по созданию своего компонента: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=2305

Answer (score 0):

Вот этим ещё воспользовался из документации
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&CHAPTER_ID=04777&LESSON_PATH=3913.3435.4777